# Why the distribution $Y/\sigma$ does not depend on $\sigma$?

Tags: bayesian, independence, scales

[This book](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-the-bugs-book/) describes the scale parameter as below:

> Suppose $\sigma$ is a scale parameter, in the sense that
>   $p(y|\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}f(y/\sigma)$ for some function $f$, so that
>   the distribution of $Y/\sigma$ does not depend on $\sigma$.

My question is:

Why "not dependent"? I think from the equation $p(y|\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}f(y/\sigma)$, we can know *nothing* about the relationship between $Y/\sigma$ and $\sigma$.

A normal distribution is tried for $Y$:

$p(y|\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$

To scale it, we get:

$p(y|\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}f(y/\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y/\sigma-\mu/\sigma)^{2}}{2}}$

So, $f(y/\sigma)$ is: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y/\sigma-\mu/\sigma)^{2}}{2}}$

Denote $y/\sigma$ as z, then $$p(z|\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(z-\mu/\sigma)^{2}}{2}}\tag{1}$$

I think the distribution of $Z$ (i.e., $Y/\sigma$) still depend on $\sigma$, because in *Equation (1)* there is $\sigma^{-1}$?

Comment: Think about what happens when you scale a normal random variable that starts off with variance of $\sigma^2$. Can you divide by a constant so that it ends up with variance $1$?

Comment: Let me give you an example: Consider $f(y/\sigma) = y/\sigma$ on $D = [0,1]$. What is the probability distribution $p(y|\sigma)$ as a function of $y$ and $\sigma$? How does this change if $D = [0,10]$?

Comment: @user40845 I was wondering what does "$D$" mean? Is it the definition domain of $y$?

Comment: @Taylor I tried the normal distribution (in my question). I find $Y/\sigma$ depends on $\sigma^{-1}$. What is wrong in my thinking?

Comment: @TX Sorry, that was unclear. In the above $D$ is the domain of $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion stems from not processing the change of variable correctly. If one sets$$Z=\sigma^{-1}Y$$the density $f_Z$ of $Z$ writes as
$$f_Z(z)=f_Y(\underbrace{\sigma z}_{y(z)}) \times \underbrace{\left|\frac{\text{d}y(z)}{\text{d}z}\right|}_\text{Jacobian}=\sigma^{-1}f(\sigma z / \sigma) \times \sigma = f(z)$$
and is therefore not dependent $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ then $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The example $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ does not work because the density of $Y$ is then indexed or parameterised by both $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score -1):

If `f(y/σ)` was such that `σ` only appeared in `f(y/σ)` as a factor multiplying the whole thing, i.e. if `f(y/σ)` could be written as `f(y/σ) = σ g(y)`, then `f(y/σ)/σ` wouldn't depend on `σ`.

Comment: Yes if $f(y/\sigma)=\sigma*g(y)$, then this $\sigma$ will disappear with $\sigma^{-1}$. But your condition is "stricter" than what the book said, which is "$f(y/\sigma)$". In additon, in your way, I suppose it's better to write $f(y*\sigma)$, why does the author write $f(y/\sigma)$?

Comment: The `/` means 2 different things. Here it means "given", not "divided by". And I just got downvoted for trying to help. Not very fair.